# How to extract metdata information from a GCP Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

How can I extract metadata information from a dataflow job like the source(PubSub) and the target(BigQuery).

I have tried going through the documentation but not able to understand how can I extract medatadata information.
Please let me know how can I achive this.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/get` and check `stageStates`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in stageStates I am not able to find metdata information.

"stageStates": [
    {
      "executionStageName": "move_start_computation_step49",
      "executionStageState": "JOB_STATE_PENDING",
      "currentStateTime": "2023-07-12T14:47:11.485Z"
    },
    {
      "executionStageName": "pause_detach_disk_step51",
      "executionStageState": "JOB_STATE_PENDING",
      "currentStateTime": "2023-07-12T14:47:11.485Z"
    },
    {
      "executionStageName": "setup_resource_global_gce_worker_pool36",
      "executionStageState": "JOB_STATE_DONE",

Comment: Try to set the view https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/JobView when you calling the API. From https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.dataflow.v1beta3#job, pipeline_description might contain more details.

Comment: Thanks XQ Hu. I am able to get the source and destination